# How can I ensure the lineReader has finished running and populating the array before printing the array after

Tags: arrays, node.js, readline, fs

This code is supposed to read a file line-by-line, grab the data it needs, and then put it into the timeStamps array. While it does put the data in the array, it continues past that function and prints an empty array before the line reader can fill it. I know it fills the array because I can add a timeout of 5 seconds and it then prints out the full array. How can I implement an async function and await the linereader?

```
    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data/test.json')
});

let timeStamps = [];

lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
    if (line.includes('timestampMs')) {
        timeStamps.push(line.toString().substring(21, 34))
        console.log(timeStamps) //prints array with each element added one by one
    }
});

console.log(timeStamps)//prints empty array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linereader` emits a `close` event once it finishes, so this should print the right results:

```
lineReader.on('close', () => {
    console.log(timeStamps); //Print this when you finish reading test.json
});
```

Full example:

```
const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data/test.json')
});

let timeStamps = [];

lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
  if (line.includes('timestampMs')) {
    timeStamps.push(line.toString().substring(21, 34))
    console.log(timeStamps) //prints array with each element added one by one
  }
});

lineReader.on('close', () => {
  console.log(timeStamps)
})
```